# Sorting Gridview breaks ModalPopUp in GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, modalpopupextender

I have a gridview that has linkbuttons that call modalpopups and textboxes with values. I am trying to implement sorting for the gridview, but the if(!ispostback) statement I need for sorting prevents the modalpopup from appearing. It also does not sort the textboxes in the gridview. Is there a way to implement sorting without using ispostback in the page_load?

Here is the code for the modalpopup, gridview binding and sorting.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            ViewState["sortOrder"] = "";
            Bind_Gridview("", "");
            loadModals();
        }
    }
protected void viewModal(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
...
     mainPanel.Controls.Add(exstModal);
        mainPanel.Controls.Add(exstModalBox);
        exstModalBox.Show();
}

protected void GridView1_Sorting(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)
    {
        Bind_Gridview(e.SortExpression, sortOrder);
    }

public string sortOrder
    {
        get
        {
            if (ViewState["sortOrder"].ToString() == "desc")
            {
                ViewState["sortOrder"] = "asc";
            }
            else
            {
                ViewState["sortOrder"] = "desc";
            }

            return ViewState["sortOrder"].ToString();
        }
        set
        {
            ViewState["sortOrder"] = value;
        }
    }

protected void gv1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
...
CheckBox cb = new CheckBox();
        TextBox ca = new TextBox();
        ca.Width = 20;
        TextBox cga = new TextBox();
        cga.Width = 20;

if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow) //Foreach row in gridview
        {

    while (dr1.Read())
            {
                ca.Text = dr1["cyla"].ToString();
                cga.Text = dr1["cga"].ToString();
                checkText = dr1["completed"].ToString();
                if (checkText == "True")
                {
                    cb.Checked = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    cb.Checked = false;
                }
            }
...
            dr1.Close();
            conn1.Close();
            e.Row.Cells[6].Controls.Add(ca);
            e.Row.Cells[8].Controls.Add(cga);
            e.Row.Cells[9].Controls.Add(cb);
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A GridView has built-in sorting capabilities. Depending on the dataset you are using to populate the data, you likely don't need to manually handle anything manually, let alone with the ViewState.

Check out the second example on this MSDN page and note that it never does anything manually with the ViewState... the `OnSorting` and `OnSorted` events are there just to display extra information or to impose requirements:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.sorting.aspx

If you post a bit more of your code (including your .aspx pages, the markup for the modal popups, and the code for the `loadModals()` function, we might be able to better help you.

Comment: I am creating BoundFields and have a RowDataBound event to fill the gridview in the backend. I though creating the sorting functionality programmatically was the only way.